# How to upgrade Jaunty 9.04 to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm very new to linux and have Jaunty 9.04 installed on my computer.

What are the steps should I take to upgrade it to 12.04?

When I use Upgrade manager, it tells me "upgrade from jaunty to lucid is not supported with this tool".

Thank you

Comment: Just do a fresh install, it will take far less time and be fare less prone to errors. Your data in /home will be preserved.

Comment: backup your data and do a fresh install, that's the easiest way and the fastest. A lot have changed since 9.04...